# Django runfcgi mode timeout

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

```
manage runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8002 maxrequests=200 maxchildren=100 minchildren=4
```

I started django fcgi in this way. It seems all right in processes monitor. But when I open http://127.0.0.1:8002, it keep runing and no result come out.

```
manage runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

This method was fine. Does any one knows why?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [Django docs on FastCGI](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/fastcgi/):

> FastCGI is an efficient way of letting
>   an external application serve pages to
>   a Web server. The Web server delegates
>   the incoming Web requests (via a
>   socket) to FastCGI, which executes the
>   code and passes the response back to
>   the Web server, which, in turn, passes
>   it back to the client’s Web browser.

You're trying to connect directly to the FCGI process from your browser, which won't work: you need an FCGI-compliant webserver to handle your request and delegate it to Django.

See the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) for a thorough explanation of how to set this up.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! It turns out that I config-ed nginx server as a proxy, which should be fast_cgi setting!